# Weapon types in Centipede?

Tags: centipede

What are the names of the array of weapons you can have in the game Centipede (1998 PC version)? What are the effects they can do? I don't just want to know all of the blaster abilities. I also want to know the Destroyer abilities (bombs,rockets). If people could leave their answer in a bulleted or numbered fashion that would help me the most.